# Streamlit executable from pyinstaller works when launching in terminal, but not by double clicking

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller, streamlit

I have `main.py` (a simple Streamlit GUI):

```py
import streamlit as st

st.text("This program is running")
```

And `wrapper.py` in the same dir:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["streamlit", "run", "main.py"])
```

When I run the command `pyinstaller --onefile --clean -w --add-data "main.py;." wrapper.py`, an executable is created (without errors), and I can run this executable  as `.\dist\wrapper.exe`, but when I double click it (in Windows), I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrapper.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "subprocess.py", line 548, in run
  File "subprocess.py", line 1024, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1493, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have checked quite a few similar questions, but couldn't find a solution for my specific case.